# How Elastic / Static IP addresses work, specifically why they need one per "region"

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, domain, google-cloud-platform, local-area-network

I am looking at Google Cloud and AWS and when you select "reserve static IP address" essentially, it requires you to specify a region like us-east-1, etc. I understand that regions are different data centers, but I'm not sure what the process is for IP addresses being used with regards to domain names....

Specifically, say you have a website such as `mywebsite.com`. I'm wondering how this gets mapped to a static IP address of some sort, or if it even needs to be static and instead can be dynamic.

What I'm imagining so far is that there is a 1-1 mapping of IP address to domain name. So `mywebsite.com` might be mapped to the globally unique public static IP of `123.123.123.123`, and then this does load balancing to distribute it to a bunch of servers.

But what is lacking from that understanding is where regions come in. If I want to "support different regions", so requests get handled faster, I would imagine I would have servers running in a specific region. These servers all handle the request for the domain `mywebsite.com`. But what I don't understand is if there are *multiple IP addresses* (static IP addresses I'm guessing), *all mapping to the same domain*, how the thing picks which IP address to use. Wondering if it is physically based on the systems interconnected. So my request on my laptop to `mywebsite.com` goes to my LAN to the WAN to the closest region somehow, figuring out that "Oh I need to go to 123.123.123.123 for region east, not 123.123.123.124 which is for region west.". Then the request is handled by the local servers and such. I get that end part.

What I'm missing is how it selects the appropriate IP address if there are multiple IP addresses associated to a domain, for multi-region optimization support.

Answer (score 1):

Public clouds generally attempt to make their regions entirely independent, to isolate failure domains.  Containing an IP in a region forces designs to not rely on the network of one region.

Directing traffic to the appropriate region is up to you. Some options:

- Active/Passive, point DNS to one region at a time.
- Global Site Load Balancer (GSLB) style fancy DNS with health checks.
- CDN style anycast, closest by IP routing.
- Multiple AAAA and A records in DNS. Limited control over the round robin behavior of clients.